# Android Parse.com not showing data on first opening

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

I have an application which uses Parse.com. Whenever I open my application and I go to the activity where it shows the user's favorite exercises, it doesn't show anything. If I press the back button and re-open the same activity (Favorites) it shows my favorite exercises. I have no clue why this happens and I hope somebody here can explain it to me. (I have used the F8 application as an example to start from)

The part where I think it fails for me is here:

```
Catalog.findInBackground(new FindCallback<Catalog>() {
        @Override
        public void done(List<Catalog> exercises, ParseException e) {
            Favorites.get().addListener(MyFavoritesActivity.this);

            if (e != null) {
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                toast.show();
                return;
            }

            if (exercises != null) {
                int i = 0;
                for (Catalog catalog : exercises) {
                    Log.d("Debug", "Exercise " + i + " added");
                    if (!favoritesOnly || Favorites.get().contains(catalog)) {
                        adapter.add(catalog);
                        i++;
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    });
```

The first time I open the activity the counter I log does not increase and only shows:

```
Debug Exercise 0 added
Debug Exercise 0 added
Debug Exercise 0 added
```

If I close the activity and reopen it:

```
Debug Exercise 0 added
Debug﹕ Exercise 1 added
Debug﹕ Exercise 2 added
```

Anybody that is willing to help me? If more code is required just ask.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried debugging while starting it for the 1st time? try that. See what happens.

Comment: Favorites get() { ... } is empty on first try. Second try it's 3 (the amount of exercises). But I can't find out why...

Comment: What is `Favorites`, and what does `get()` do?

Comment: `private static Favorites instance = new Favorites();` 
`public static Favorites get() { return instance; }`